# Error: expected identifier, string or number

Tags: javascript

I've been working on some javascript functionality for this site: http://bit.ly/e1oyVV

Everything is o.k in all browsers except IE 6 and 7 where I'm getting the error:

Error: expected identifier, string or number on line 236, char 3

I have no idea where to start debugging this, Im still learning so the error might be something a bit noob..

The js is in the homeFunctions.js or you can view it in pastebin here: http://pastebin.com/LDzwKFDm

The debugger seems to be pointing to the line which closes the homeFunc object... :s

Any help would be greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 3):

IE does not like the `},` on line 236

change it to a plain `}` and you should be fine